# Why does the measure of a support $1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\mu:\mathscr{B}_X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a Borel probability measure.

Define $supp(\mu)$ to be the set of all points whose every open neighborhood has a postive measure.

If $supp(\mu)$ is separable, why is $\mu(supp(\mu))=1$?

(I searched for it and I saw that this is true when $X$ is a metric space, but false in general. I cannot find a proof of it though)

Comment: Observe $ \operatorname{supp}(\mu)^C \cap \operatorname{supp}(\mu) = \emptyset$, then $1=\mu(X)=\mu(\operatorname{supp}(\mu)^C\cup \operatorname{supp}(\mu)) = \mu(\operatorname{supp}(\mu)^C) + \mu(\operatorname{supp}(\mu))$

Comment: @JackyChong I included the definition of support to make it clear. I think the definition you are referring to is not same as the one I am referring to. I think you are assuming $\mu(supp(\mu)^c)=0$, but why is that so?

Comment: I didn't assume $\mu(\operatorname{supp}(\mu)^C)=0$. I simply reduced the problem to showing $\mu(\operatorname{supp}(\mu)^C)=0$. It wasn't meant to be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false in general.  For instance, if $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, you can take $X=\kappa$ with the discrete metric and let $\mu$ be the $\{0,1\}$-valued measure corresponding to a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter.  Then $\mu$ vanishes on every singleton so its support is empty.

(Probably you can also cook up a counterexample in just ZFC, but I don't know one off the top of my head.)

It is true if you assume $X$ is separable, because the complement of the support can be covered by open sets of measure $0$ and by separability you can take a countable subcover to conclude that the complement of the support has measure $0$.

Comment: Would you please check this? : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2885102/44669

Comment: Since I do not know the concept of measurable cardinal, I cannot verify your argument. However, if your argument is correct then there is something wrong with the proof of Skorohod theorem in the above link. If we assume $X$ to be separable, then the support is automatically separable, it is weird to only assume the separability of the support..