# Why does such $M$ exist in this proof for Skorohod representation theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Reference: [Why does the measure of a support $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2885066/44669)

[image]

Billingsley - Convergence of probability measures p.70

In the proof, the author assumes the existence of a borel set $M$ such that $PM=1$. However, why does this set exist?

As you can see in my reference page, the measure of the support of $P$ need not be $1$.

Comment: Is the definition of "support" you used in the other question directly from the book?  If not, I would expect that Billingsley has a different definition in mind.

Comment: @EricWofsey The author does not give the definition of “support” in his book.. I wonder what definition he referred to then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that Billingsley is using a different definition of "support" than the one you gave in the other question.  Specifically, a support of $P$ is just any measurable set $M$ such that $PM=1$.  So, to say "$P$ has a separable support" just means that there exists such a set $M$ which is separable.  (In the case that the entire background metric space is separable, then any measure has a unique smallest closed support, which is often called *the* support, and this agrees with your definition.)

Comment: Aha.. that makes sense. Thank you!